# Tiling the hyperbolic plane with mutually-non congruent equal area triangles

Tags: discrete-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

This post continues [On tiling the plane with non-congruent, equal area triangles with each edge having a unique length](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439537/on-tiling-the-plane-with-non-congruent-equal-area-triangles-with-each-edge-havi)

1. Can the hyperbolic plane be tiled by pair-wise non-congruent equal area triangles?

A more constrained further question:

2. Can the hyperbolic plane be tiled by mutually non-congruent equal area triangles with the further constraint that every angle is unique?

Note: an earlier post on tiling the hyperbolic plane: [Which polygons tessellate the hyperbolic plane?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398191/which-polygons-tessellate-the-hyperbolic-plane)

Comment: Related: [Tiling with incommensurate triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307130/6094). My question remains open.

Comment: thanks. the earlier post linked to this question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439537/on-tiling-the-plane-with-non-congruent-equal-area-triangles-with-each-edge-havi) had referenced your question.