# Tiling the hyperbolic plane by non-regular quadrilaterals

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

We add a bit to [Which polygons tessellate the hyperbolic plane?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398191/which-polygons-tessellate-the-hyperbolic-plane).

**Question:** Are there hyperbolic quadrilaterals with all angles different (not necessarily irrational fractions of π) that tile the hyperbolic plane? What about quads with 3 of the angles equal and 1 different? If the answer to either question is "yes" one could ask for conditions under which tiling happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution: start with the equilateral hyperbolic triangle with angles $2\pi/7$, which tiles the hyperbolic plane. Cut it into three congruent quadrilaterals with angles $(2\pi/7, \pi/2+\epsilon, 2\pi/3, \pi/2-\epsilon)$, meeting at the center of the triangle.

Comment: I think one of the quadrilateral angles should be $2 \pi / 3$, not $\pi / 3$.

Comment: Yes, thanks Zerox.

Comment: Thanks for this very simple answer. The same approach - equipartitioning a regular equilateral with a 3-fan - appears to work for the elliptical plane as well. It also seems that if all  angles of a quad are irrational in units of pi, then it cannot be a tile.

Comment: Since not all convex hyperbolic quads can tile, it might be of some interest to characterize those that do tile - similar to finding all convex pentagons that can tile the euclidean plane.

Comment: If it can be shown (say) that "for large enough n, any n-gon that tiles the hyperbolic plane has necessarily to have all angles except at most, a constant number (or very small fraction of n) of angles equal" that could be hopefully interesting.